# Running the mongos Route Server as a Windows Service on 2008R2?

Tags: windows, mongodb, windows-services

I want to run mongos (that's the *mongo route server* named `mongos`, not a malformed plural, but I digress) on the server that's hosting our application layer. I need to run as a Windows service and I have poured over the directions on [10Gen's website](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Windows+Service). However, the tool set they recommend ([Windows Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?pf=true&id=17657)) is for Server 2003 (and prior) and is not recommended for use on 64-bit platforms. All my application servers are 64-bit 2008r2.

The documentation implies that mongos as a Windows service may be supported beyond v1.8.1. Has anyone had success deploying mongos as a Windows service on a 2008 server? If there is no native support, is there another version of the resource kit, or did you roll your own service wrapper?

Thanks for any information you may have.

-Seth

Comment: From experience: `srvany.exe` runs fine on 08 R2. The other tools in the WRK may not.

Comment: For future reference, there is some good info on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/questions/325021/running-mongos-as-a-reliable-service-on-windows-server-2008r2-64-bit) about this as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The request to add built-in support for running mongos.exe as a Windows service (the way you can run mongod.exe as a service) is outstanding as https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1589 -- you can vote for it to show your support.

srvany.exe does work in Windows Server 2008 R2 using the directions you referenced: I just tested it with MongoDB 2.0.2.  The srvany.exe process is 32-bits, but it runs a 64-bit mongos.exe just fine.

Comment: Thanks, Tad. I'll go vote up that ticket. We're verifying srvany on our app server now. Part of this whole exercise is getting our SysOps team comfortable with whatever we go with because none of it is "officially" supported.